# Waiting to pitch yeast?

Tags: beer, fermentation-temperature, lager, lagering

I came across a couple similar questions, but not exactly what I was looking for.

I only have a short period where I have time to brew, but my starter isn't ready and some cooling equipment. Are there any concerns or side affects to brewing like normal then transferring to a sanitized fermentor with airlock and not pitching until the next day or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives an increased chance for bacteria to take over from the yeast if your sanitation isn't impeccable.

That said, many Australian homebrewers cool their wort overnight (the no chill method) and pitch their yeast the next day. I'm not planning on trying that, but it seems to work for them without introducing bacteria since they sanitize properly.

You have a few options:

1. Pitch your yeast starter immediately. If your yeast is already viable and your beer isn't too high gravity, you can pitch without a starter and be perfectly fine most of the time.
2. Make absolutely sure everything is sanitized properly and pitch the next day or later in the day.

Comment: Regarding the Aussie "No Chill" method, the wort is poured into a plastic vessel that can be sealed airtight will the wort is still very hot. I wouldn't try it unless you have that piece of equipment. FWIW, I No Chill 95% of my beers now.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible method if you have a lid to your brew kettle is to clean and sterilize the lid either by conventional sterilization methods or cover it a little before flame out so that the lid is sterilzed by the heat and steam.  Then just wait till morning when the wort has fully cooled and transfer it into a sterilized container, being careful not to transfer the trub from the bottom of the kettle.  Then pitch immediately.  This approach has the added benefit that you can leave the trub in the kettle.  I have seen this successfully used and was being used by a molecular biologist who was quite keen on sterile technique.  As long as I knew him he never had bacterial infection in his brew.

Comment: Don't you worry about DMS formation? My understanding is hot (>140 F.) wort continues to generate DMS. Without the mechanical action of the boil, the DMS will remain in solution and affect the flavor of the beer. This is one of the main motivations for rapid chilling post-boil.

Comment: I never noticed a DMS taste in the beer from the person who used this method.  However, based on Palmer (http://www.howtobrew.com/section4/chapter21-2.html) this method of cooling will likely introduce more DMS.  Some of it will be trapped on the condensed water on the lid, and thus carefully removing the lid to reduce transfer of water on the lid to the wort might help a bit.  Not saying this method is optimal in any way shape or form, but it does work if you are looking for ways to cut time.